# Cannot find any service with service name 'MSSQLSERVER' on docker-compose build

Tags: docker

Has anyone ever run into the error below when running a build for Sitecore 10.1? It used to work fine and now this error pops up. I'm adding SPE and SXA to MSSQL. Again, it just started breaking but worked in the past.

Here is the code in the *dockerfile* that generates the error now:

```
# Add SPE module
COPY --from=spe \module\db \spe_data
RUN C:\DeployDatabases.ps1 -ResourcesDirectory C:\spe_data; `
    Remove-Item -Path C:\spe_data -Recurse -Force;
```

Here is the error on docker-compose build:

```
Step 11/15 : RUN C:\DeployDatabases.ps1 -ResourcesDirectory C:\spe_data;     Remove-Item -Path C:\spe_data -Recurse -Force;
 ---> Running in bffa4ae2ed24
Start-Service : Cannot find any service with service name 'MSSQLSERVER'.
At C:\DeployDatabases.ps1:78 char:5
+     Start-Service MSSQLSERVER;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Since the MSSQLSERVICE service exists in the `mssql` Sitecore base images, it looks like step 11/15 in your Dockerfile is getting executed on the wrong base image. Can you share your entire Dockerfile?

Comment: Hi @AlessandroFaniuolo I'm not sure how the base image could have changed? I haven't modified the code and it has worked on several builds. Only recently did this error occur. I did update Docker Desktop to the next update, but I don't think that would cause this issue.

If I strip out the module adds in the MS SQL build it does complete. However, when the container starts the log file says this:

C:\StartInit.ps1 : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'SqlServer' because it is 
an empty string.
At line:1 char:143
+ ... urcesDirectory $env:RESOURCES_PATH -SqlServer $env:SQL_SERVER -SqlAd

Comment: One thing that could cause the wrong base image to be used is having the wrong order of the `FROM` commands in the Dockerfile (this is why I asked you to share your entire Dockerfile).

Comment: Understood. That is why I tried stripping out the modules. But again, the odd thing is that  it all worked before and is straight from Sitecore. Here is the file now that allows the build, but the container fails with the message above. Thanks for looking!

FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

Comment: The `StartInit.ps1` script is the entrypoint script of the `mssql-init` image, not of the `mssql` image. Are you trying to build a custom mssql-init image or installing the modules in the mssql image?

Comment: I'm installing the modules in the mssql image. It worked before, but maybe I should add the init image and add my modules there instead. Not sure why this would stop working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131262/discussion-between-alessandro-faniuolo-and-dan-poincelot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the error shared in the comment above:

> C:\StartInit.ps1 : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'SqlServer' because it is an empty string. At line:1 char:143 + ... urcesDirectory $env:RESOURCES_PATH -SqlServer $env:SQL_SERVER -SqlAd

It seems that the base image used as build argument is a `mssql-init` image and not a `mssql` image, because the `StartInit.ps1` entrypoint is the entrypoint script of a `mssql-init` image. This explains why the build process fails when trying to start the SQL Server service, that of course doesn't exist in a `mssql-init` image.

Comment: Thank you! I was in the process of changing to 10.2 and left something behind....doh. Thanks for taking it into chat to really get a look at the issue.